# Android Marshmallow error:GoogleService failed to initialize, status: 10, Missing an expected resource:

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have a android application.In this application i implement push notification by google GCM.It working well below Marshmallow.But when i open this application into Marshmallow then it doesn't open the application.It show a error message.

> GoogleService failed to initialize, status: 10, Missing an expected resource: 'R.string.google_app_id' for initializing Google services.  Possible causes are missing google-services.json or com.google.gms.google-services gradle plugin

Only i get this error for Marshmallow.But other version working well .Don't understand what is issues for Marshmallow.Please give to me any suggestion how i can solve this error for Marshmallow.Thanks All.

Comment: So do you have a `google-services.json` file and have you used the `com.google.gms.google-services` gradle plugin as per the [getting started with GCM on Android guide](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start)?

Comment: This happens for me as well with a MotoX running 5.0.2

Comment: For those who face this problem even after correctly setting up play services and placing `google-services.json` file in `project/app` folder, the actual solution is to 

`Build > Rebuild Project`


Possibly due to the fact that strings from json file are not integrated into compiled resources until a full rebuild is performed.